# Using jQuery noconflict with two versions of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

> The issue is that if you want to use otherLibrary on the page, $ must be otherLibrary's $, not jQuery's. Since $ is just an alias for jQuery anyway, jQuery provides the noConflict function as a means of telling jQuery to return control of $ back to whatever had it before jQuery was loaded.

I read this on another question. I am making a change on a site that currently uses jQuery 1.3.2, which it cannot update, and other libraries. It currently uses noConflict so that one must use `jQuery` in place of `$`. I need to run a new version of jQuery for an addition being added to the page.

How can I call this second jQuery library and use noConflict to associate a new alias to it? So that `jQuery` works for 1.3.2, the new alias works for the second jQuery, and $ works for everything else?

Comment: `var jQ132 = $.noConflict(true);`

Comment: Load the "second jQuery" first, use `$.noConflict()` to assign it to the alias. Then load jQuery 1.3.2, which will take `jQuery` and `$`. Then load "everything else" last so they take the `$`.

Comment: Have you considered [reading the documentation for `$.noConflict`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)? It even gives you demos for using two versions of jQuery.

Comment: what is *"everything else"*?

Comment: @squint I did, and honestly, that is why I came here. I've seen too many conflicting examples that explain high-level stuff and omit specific things. I really just need a boiled-down answer like jbabey's. For example, gdoron's answer - which of the two loaded jQuery libraries does his jQ132 alias assign to? The first one? Last one? I almost wish you could do something like `<script src="jquery-1.1.0?noConflictAlias=j"></script>`

Comment: well, he named it jQ132 for a reason.

Comment: @KevinB, Still needs to explain how you ensure that it is assigned to that library. Is it so because the noConflict is called right after calling 1.3.2? Is it order dependent? Is "jQ132" a reserved name? So on...

Comment: Without doing any $.noconflict, $ will reference the most recently included version of jQuery. Therefore, calling var foo = $.noConflict(true) will return the most recently included version of jQuery to the foo variable and set `$` equal to the previously included version of jQuery. I don't think it's that difficult to understand.

Comment: @user1729506: The demo in the docs shows how to check the jQuery version. Follow the example and see what happens. Sometimes you've just got to be willing to get your hands a little dirty.

Answer (score 3):

Quoting the example from the api, with added plugins:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.superautocomplete.js"></script> <!-- this uses 1.9.1 -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script> <!-- this uses 1.3.2 -->

<script>
/*
Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
(the newer version)
*/
jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jq132("[rel=fancybox]").fancybox(); // using 1.3.2
$("#autocomplete").superautocomplete(); // using 1.9.1
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is an *extremely* simplified version of what is going on inside jQuery when you call no conflict.

```
// including first version of jQuery:
window._foo = window.foo; // undefined
window.foo = "1.9.1"; // 1.9.1

// including second version of jQuery:
window._foo = window.foo; // 1.9.1
window.foo = "1.3.2"; // 1.3.2

// now when you do noConflict, this happens:
function noConflict() {
    var ret = window.foo; // 1.3.2
    window.foo = window._foo; // 1.9.1
    return ret; // 1.3.2
}

foo132 = noConflict(); // 1.3.2
alert(foo132); //1.3.2
alert( foo ); // 1.9.1
```

Comment: When you use noConflict in this manner, does it associate the alias to the absolute last called jQuery library?

Comment: Yes, because the absolute last included library is the one that is stored in $ at that point in time.

Comment: For example, `foo = 1; _foo = foo; foo = 2;` `foo` will equal `2`.