# Wordpress more than 2 versions jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress site, the problem is that i have more than 2 versions of jquery.

The problem is that the navbar won't work on a single page, namely this:

http://staging.skyberate.nl/shared-hosting/magento-hosting/referenties/

If you see, the navbar href's still works, but the dropdown won't. But on other pages it works fine.

I was reading this:

http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/10/03/using-multiple-versions-of-jquery/

But i don't know how to use this on wordpress, because everything is dynamic. Even a single page is dynamic...

Comment: any reason for using more than 2versions of jquery

Comment: I dont know, i didn't made the whole site. The navbar is 3.8 i think and what i made on a single page something like 1,8. I don't know why, i'm really new to jquery

Comment: Remove the 2nd jquery include.. which file handles the js for your nav?

Comment: Uhhm i'm going to have a look which one it is.. But when i delete the second one, the js on my page won't work anymore?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed!

The problem was that in the header of the site. There was linked to a jQuery library on the webserver itselves and my own jQuery was linked to a jQuery library from google.
So I copied the path from the servers library itselves and paste that instead of the link to the google library and that works fine!

Answer (score 1):

**Create a different alias instead of jQuery** to use in the rest of the script.

```
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

**Do something with jQuery** ***(use alise j instead of $ where your script is conflict)***

```
j( "div p" ).hide();
```

**Do something with another library's $()**

$( "content" ).style.display = "none";

=================================================================================
Other example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery.superautocomplete.js"></script> <!-- this uses 1.9.1 -->
</head>
<body>

<div id="log">
  <h3>Before $.noConflict(true)</h3>
</div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.fancybox.js"></script> <!-- this uses 1.3.2 -->

<script>
/*
Restore globally scoped jQuery variables to the first version loaded
(the newer version)
*/
jq132 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
jq132("[rel=fancybox]").fancybox(); // using 1.3.2
$("#autocomplete").superautocomplete(); // using 1.9.1
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

[Referrence from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699329/using-jquery-noconflict-with-two-versions-of-jquery#answer-16699753)