# can i use any version of jquery using jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

im using this plugin https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin,

but my jquery version is 1.4, so i used `jQuery.noConflict()` because someone said that i can use any version of jquery through this one:

`var jq10 = jQuery.noConflict();`

but when i try to use the plugin it won't work, it won't have errors too, so i don't know if my code is wrong, or it just doesn't work even with `jQuery.noConflict()`. Anyone has idea? Here is a sample of what I'm doing, very simple but it doesn't work, or doesn't have any errors to give me a hint

```
<html>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload" multiple>
</html>

//This is my original version
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
//This is the minimum version required of the plugin
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
//These are the requirements for the plugin
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>

$(document).ready( function() {
    var jq10 = jQuery.noConflict();

    jq10('#fileupload').fileupload({
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

You see, i just console logged the data, but it won't return anything with firebug, won't have errors or any to give me a hint of what's going on.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict` let's you use 2 versions of jQuery on one page.  It let's the 1st version be `$`, and the 2nd one be something else (like `jq10`).  It's so the 2 versions don't "conflict" with each other.  It's usually only used if a plugin won't work with your version of jQuery.

Comment: yes, i already did that. But it's weird cause it still doesnt work. Help me on this one

Comment: Can you show where you are loading your scripts and where you call `jQuery.noConflict()`?

Comment: I updated it already, please check it out

Comment: I thought every input control comes under body :) Jokes apart, you should really improve your html check out the link http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
// Do something with jQuery
jQuery( "div p" ).hide();
// Do something with another library's $()
$( "content" ).style.display = "none";
```

so,

```
var jq10 = jQuery.noConflict();
jq10(document).ready( function() {

$('#fileupload').fileupload({
    dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: i get `$ is not a function` error same as the first answer

Answer (score 0):

Replace everything with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" name="files[]" id="fileupload" multiple>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/new_jquery/fileupload/js/jquery.fileupload.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.noConflict();
        jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
            // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
            $('#fileupload').fileupload({
                dataType: 'json',
                add: function (e, data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, someone has told you wrong. You cannot use different versions of jquery, if you use `$.noConflict()`. (*Ok, you can, but it is not recommended*)

## But wait !

You shouldn't load two versions of jquery at all. This is just ridiculous if you do that way.

## But yes

If you really have to use a plugin that's too old or depends on a older jquery version.

Comment: Do i have to separate the document.ready for each different versions? i mean do i have to build TWO 'document.ready' each for the different versions?

Comment: Don't load 2 versions of jquery. Its wrong. Load only one

Comment: Can you modify your answer to make it obvious? really i dont get it. sorry for being noob here

Comment: @user2881063, check out now.

Comment: So I can still use the plugin and make fully use of its functionality even if my jquery version is very outdated?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.4, and that plugin requires 1.6, why you put 1.6 there? and why is the use of the plugin inside the document.ready? now all of my codes that uses my original jquery version goes out of the document.ready? as what your comment says: Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.

Comment: yeah, don't include 1.4, just include 1.6 and it should work fine. Mark it as answer if it helps !

Comment: The other library means other libraries like angularjs, react, zepto etc. For now, since you are new , just copy and paste my answer

Comment: I cannot use jquery 1.6, because all of my pages uses 1.4, that means i have to put jQuery.noConflict on all of my pages. Isnt there any way?

Comment: NO, NO, NO. Nothing will happen, because the syntax is basically same.

Comment: While you're correct @AmitJoki, he shouldn't have to use two versions of jQuery you're incorrect - you CAN use two versions of jQuery in a web page by using noConflict(). Many people have been using noConflict(), especially if a plugin has not been upgraded to a newer version of jQuery and will not work with a newer version. Is it best practice? No, not really. Is it practical? In some cases very much so.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, first, if you do `jquery.noConflict()`,how do you know which version gets executed ?

Comment: If you do noConflict() the each version of jQuery will be 'assigned' to an alias. You use those alias' to run the things that need to be run with each version. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699329/using-jquery-noconflict-with-two-versions-of-jquery

Comment: thnx, mate. Now I know